# Integrate a Google Hangout link in a calendar invite from a 3rd party site (not from Gmail)

Tags: google-hangouts

In the site I manage, users can schedule meetings with one another and connect on Google Hangout, but they have to find each other on Google+ or send a calendar invite from Gmail with a hangout link.

Is there anyway to automatically integrate a hangout link into the invite / e-mail notification from our site, so that if both users click, they enter into a unique Google Hangout session?